# Getting all question on a keyword served

Tags: discussion

I'm a lazy person when it comes to non-challenging tasks. So, I'd like to get notified of all the new questions for e.g. "Dynamics-CRM-2011" (either by mail or or other means - I'm flexible).

How can that be done?

If possible, is it achievable so that I get updates on the postings in close-to-real time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already ways available to you to follow the activity in a tag of your choice. Hovering over a specific tag will reveal a window with the tag wiki excerpt and various links.

[image]

At the top right you will find two links you might use. Either subscribe to email notifications for the tag, or follow the tag's RSS feed.

The email subscription can be set to a frequency of once a day, once every 3 hours or once every 15 minutes, by going to the management page for the specific subscription within your network profile.

[image]